# rotation and scaling is not working in edit mode in blender 3.2.2

Tags: edit-mode, transforms

Can anyone please tell me why it's not working?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What do you want? You want to scale a point? It's not possible, it is 1-dimetional object. Instead, you can change the point radius:

[image]

With the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Yes, Alt+s is worked

Comment: The same applies to rotating. You can only rotate if you have more than one point selected.